# AdminLTE 3 Roles

Tags: laravel, users-roles, adminlte

Hola estoy creando un proyecto en Laravel y he usado la interfaz AdminLTE 3 para el dashboard.

Mi dudad es: como puedo configurar el archivo adminlte.php de forma que el "menu intem" muestre unas secciones u otras dependiendo del "rol" que tenga asignado el usuario?? He probado con @rol('prueba') pero no es correcto y no hallo la forma.

```
'menu' => [
    // Navbar items:
    [
        'type'         => 'navbar-search',
        'text'         => 'search',
        'topnav_right' => true,
    ],
    [
        'type'         => 'fullscreen-widget',
        'topnav_right' => true,
    ],
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

espero que ya hayas podido resolver tu problema, pero si no es así, te dijo como lo resolví yo.

En vez de hacerlo en el archivo config/adminlte.php, debes hacerlo en el archivo app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php en la función boot().

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public function boot()
{
    Event::listen(BuildingMenu::class, function (BuildingMenu $event) {

        //Aquí agregas todos los menús que necesites.
        //Puedes realizar una consulta y luego recorrerla para ir agregando cada uno.
        $event->menu->add([
            'text'  => $menu->nombre,
            'url'   => $menu->url,
            'icon'  => $menu->icono, //Icono de fontawesome
            'can'   => $menu1->can,  //Este campo indica si el usuario no tiene el permiso indicado, este menu no se mostrara. (Yo trabajo con laravel-permission de Spatie)
            'submenu' => $subMenusItem, //Solo si el menú tiene submenus
        ]);
    });
}
```

Le puedes agregar todos los atributos que necesites.

Espero que esto te pueda orientar.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que aún te sirva. Si usas la librería Spatie\Permission, solo tienes que agregar 'can'=>'permiso' en cada item del menú que requieras.

```
'menu' => [
  // Navbar items:
  [
    'type'         => 'navbar-search',
    'text'         => 'search',
    'topnav_right' => true,
    'can'          => 'permiso',
  ],
  [
    'type'         => 'fullscreen-widget',
    'topnav_right' => true,
  ],
```

'permiso' debes tenerlo registrado en tu base de datos. Para ello, creas un RoleSeeder con los roles y permisos para que automáticamente te genere las tablas necesarias en la base de datos.

Te dejo el link de la librería https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v6/advanced-usage/seeding